# Can't run gitlab runner with shell

Tags: git, powershell, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

This is the error I am getting, I have no clue what is wrong.
[image]

Comment: Have you done what the error told you to do?

Comment: Yes, no information provided on that page could help resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the powershell executable is not in your environmental PATH variable. This can be verified with:

```
echo $env:path
```

To add the path you your Powershell enter:

```
$env:path="$env:path;C:\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
```

You will need to verify the location on you local system and verify the version accordingly.

Comment: I did that but it gives me the same error. Do I have to re-install or re-register the runner?